# Fetching the rows from db table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Below is my db table.

```
 RECORDNO| STAGE| COMMENT | STATE
 12      | 1    | abcd    | P
 13      | 1    | adfg    | P
 14      | 2    | adsds   | P
 15      | 2    | defe    | P
```

I want to fetch the records which has State'P' and stage = stage of  minimum recordno ;

```
SELECT * 
  FROM history 
 WHERE STATE = 'P' 
   AND recordNO = ( SELECT MIN(record#) 
                      FROM history 
                     WHERE STATE = 'P' ) ;
```

The above query gives only the row with recordno 12. I want to fetch rows with recordno 12 and 13 .
Please help me with the query.

Comment: What's your DBMS and version?

Answer (score 0):

For MySql use this:

```
SELECT h.* FROM history h
WHERE  h.STATE = 'P' 
   AND h.STAGE = (SELECT STAGE FROM history WHERE STATE = h.STATE ORDER BY RECORDNO LIMIT 1);
```

The subquery in the `WHERE` clause returns the stage of minimum recordno.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/imKJxd8rR2B8NJEeDGjfgf/1).

For Oracle 12c+ change `LIMIT 1` with:

```
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0032ee2b6ad1a2724c5bab17ad81a440).

Results:

```
| RECORDNO | STAGE | COMMENT | STATE |
| -------- | ----- | ------- | ----- |
| 12       | 1     | abcd    | P     |
| 13       | 1     | adfg    | P     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:

```
    select * from history
    where stage in 
        ( select stage from history where recordno = 
            ( select min(recordno) from history where state = 'P' )
        );
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c9b1/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

A subquery match for STAGE column with MINIMUM of STAGE

```
SELECT h1.* 
  FROM history h1
 WHERE h1.STATE = 'P' 
   AND h1.STAGE = (SELECT MIN(STAGE) FROM history );
```

Or An Inline view through JOIN keyword

```
SELECT h1.* 
  FROM history h1
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(STAGE) AS STAGE FROM history ) h2
    ON h2.STAGE = h.STAGE
 WHERE h1.STATE = 'P';
```

for both of the DBMS(<kbd>[MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b48a58ac6e5f0807f7a74d35791cad2)</kbd>&<kbd>[Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=284d814ca611fecf06883731164e806e)</kbd>).